# Cannot start Weblogic 12c inside Netbeans. No main class given to java

Tags: netbeans, weblogic, weblogic12c

I try to run an application in Weblogic 12c server. I setup the weblogic server in Netbeans.

When I run the project, the following error is produced:

```
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
Starting WLS with line:
c:\java\jdk1.7.0_21\\bin\java   -Dweblogic.Name= -Djava.security.policy=\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|Toshiba-TOSH"  
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
...
```

Netbeans doesn't give the class name to the `java` command. Therefore the server doesn't start. Normally, it should have been something like `java weblogic.Server`.

Why is the main class not specified here?

It is weird that during installation Weblogic didn't ask or give me the default password. In the Servers setup of Netbeans, I specified "weblogic123" as the password for the user "weblogic". Maybe the above error might be related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this error.

The domain that Weblogic server runs was faulty. I had copied the domain folder from another computer. The paths in that domain's files were different than mine.

I redefined a domain in my own Weblogic using Configuration Wizard. Then the application run properly.